# assign javascript variable to a velocity template variable

Tags: java, javascript, velocity

In my velocity template, I have a javascript variable like

```
var workflowInstanceNameText = document.getElementById('workflowInstanceName').value;
```

and I want to assign the javascript variable to velocity template variable.

```
#set(workflowName = 'someexpression here');
```

In the palce of some expression I have tried as below but its not assigning value

```
 #set(workflowName = workflowInstanceNameText);
 #set(workflowName = $workflowInstanceNameText);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Velocity works on server side. JavaScript works on client side (browser). You can generate JavaScript using Velocity, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity templating happens on the server side. So, if you want your javascript variable that is on the client-side to be available during velocity template stage on the server side, you have to send that variable as a request parameter to your server-side servlet/action and refer to that request parameter in your velocity template.